# Compare values beween 2 columns and return value of a third column

Tags: r, tidyverse

In a dataframe we have:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| E | 1 | 3 |
| F | 2 | 2 |
| G | 3 | 1 |

I would like to create a Column D based on the following logic: match each column C value with column B and return the value of Column A that corresponds to the position of the matched value.

in this case it would look like this:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| E | 1 | 3 | G |
| F | 2 | 2 | F |
| G | 3 | 1 | E |

I have tried the following:

```
data<-data %>% 
      mutate(D = case_when(C%in%B~A))
```

but it returns the value of column A that matches column B and not column C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `match`,

```
df$ColumnD <- df$ColumnA[match(df$ColumnC, df$ColumnB)]
#[1] "G" "F" "E"
```

Or in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
 mutate(ColumnD = ColumnA[match(ColumnC, ColumnB)])

  ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC ColumnD
1       E       1       3       G
2       F       2       2       F
3       G       3       1       E
```

**DATA**

```
dput(df)
structure(list(ColumnA = c("E", "F", "G"), ColumnB = 1:3, ColumnC = 3:1), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have columns `B` and `C` in your data, I assume the first part of your instructions ("match each column B value with column C") is already completed? Otherwise you would end up with the exact same column as `A`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~A, ~B, ~C,
        "E",        1L,        3L,
        "F",        2L,        2L,
        "G",        3L,        1L
  )

mutate(df, D = A[C])
#> # A tibble: 3 × 4
#>   A         B     C D    
#>   <chr> <int> <int> <chr>
#> 1 E         1     3 G    
#> 2 F         2     2 F    
#> 3 G         3     1 E
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

In your code, the line `case_when(C%in%B~A)` means that you take the value from column `A` whenever the value from `C` can be found *anywhere* in column `B`. This is true for all values in this example so you just get a duplicate column of `A` in return.

Comment: I tried to rephrase it above so it is more clear. I have B and C completed. I want to take each value from column C and match it with the value of column B and return that column A value that corresponds with the match. So in the example above if we take the first column I would like to search 3 (the first value of column C) within column B and return the column A value that correspond to the position of the 3 in column B (in this case G).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete other approach using `right_join`:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  right_join(data, by=c("B"="C")) %>% 
  select(A=A.x, B, C, D=A.y)

  A B C D
1 E 1 3 G
2 F 2 2 F
3 G 3 1 E
```